# Full ionization meaning

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics

I'm confused as to what full ionization mean? I have the mean molecular weight of electrons and ions and I have to calculate the ideal gas pressure for a star. Do I have to add them up as usual or do I use only the mean molecular weight of ions?

Comment: The proton mass is about 2000 times the electron mass, so it might be reasonable to neglect the electrons entirely. Depends on the accuracy of your calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full ionization means that the electrons are no longer bound to the nuclei: the electrons and the nuclei behave as independent particles. I think this means you can treat them as a gas - the same way that you would treat a mixture of gases.